# Showing and Hiding Div with CSS

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, header

I am trying to hide a div and display another according to the users screen size. So I would like to hide one header on desktop and display another, vice versa for mobile. This is currently what I am trying.

This is the asp that I have for both of the headers.

```
<div id="headerContainer" class="container a" style="background-color: white;">
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <img src="Images/JDC Logo No Border Jpg Smaller.png" class="img-responsive" style=" padding-top: 4%;" alt="JD&C Services Logo - Header Image"/> <!--img-responsive-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <button ID="BTN_Home" class="headerButtons hvr-underline-from-center " runat="server" onserverclick="BTN_Home_ServerClick">HOME</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <button ID="BTN_OHS" class="headerButtons hvr-underline-from-center " runat="server" onserverclick="BTN_OHS_ServerClick" href="Safety.aspx" >SAFETY</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <button ID="BTN_Services" class="headerButtons hvr-underline-from-center " runat="server" onserverclick="BTN_Services_ServerClick" >SERVICES</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <button ID="BTN_Careers" class="headerButtons hvr-underline-from-center headerPadding" runat="server" onserverclick="BTN_Careers_ServerClick">CAREERS</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <button ID="BTN_Contact" class="headerButtons hvr-underline-from-center " runat="server" onserverclick="BTN_Contact_ServerClick">CONTACT</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="expandableHeader2" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="expandableHeader">
      <h1><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></h1>
      <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS that I am using to hide and display the headers.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1240px){
    #expandableHeader{
        display: inline !important;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #expandableHeader2{
        display: inline !important;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #headerContainer{
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1241px){
    #expandableHeader, #expandableHeader2{
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

So the issue that I am having is on desktop it works fine. I am able to hide the expandable header, and display the main header fine. But on mobile it is not working fully. On mobile, the main header becomes hidden, but the expandable header is not shown. I am not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the "headerContainer" `</div>`

Just add `</div>` before

```
<div id="expandableHeader2" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/jdjor7nm/

Comment: My apologies, I do have that in my code, I just accidentally didn't add it into the question. It is editited now.

Comment: I have the `</div>` included in the SO question, but it is not showing up for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I needed to move the second div outside the other. This worked out great. Thank you!